# Cannot select html td link button by XPath with Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, xpath, chromedriver

Here is my element

```
<td>
<div class="linkButton" onclick="window.open('../../Report/Reports/ViewReport.aspx?reportName=Revenue.Report','Report1','scrollbars=1,resizable=yes,width=800,height=600');">Revenue Report</div>
</td>
```

I have tried the following XPaths:

```
//td[contains(text(), 'Revenue Report')]

//*[contains(@onclick, 'Revenue.Report')]
```

Both fail with "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Are there other options for selecting this web element?

Answer (score 1):

There're usually more options, e.g.:

```csharp
// CSS
currentDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td > div.linkButton"));
currentDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.linkButton"));
// xPath
currentDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Revenue Report']"));
```

Another problem might be with element visibility, you can search this site for more information on that. Selenium WebDriver with C# binding doesn't have any retry policy, so you basically need to wait for elements and their states.

Answer (score 1):

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Revenue Report')]
//td[contains(string(), 'Revenue Report')]
```

use any of the above locator, the text is inside div tag and not td.